# With yolov5 how should I improve the identification of tea buds map@0.5?

Tags: object-detection, yolov5

My data set looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqtWc.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scMEY.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRyUL.jpg)

I used yolov5s to get the best map@0.5 only 0.86, using yolov5m, L,x would be even lower.
This is the result of running on yolov5s[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvsB1.png)

I tried adding attention mechanics and a small target detection layer, but the results were lower.
Train has 2520 pictures, Val has 630 and Test has 100.
What can I do to raise map@0.5 above 0.9, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try following steps:

0. Most important - check your training data, may be there are some errors, due to which the generalizing ability of the model worsens
1. Due to the relatively small size of objects you can use higher input resolution
2. Because your targets differ in color from other objects, don't use aggressive color-space augmentations

Comment: many thx. I annotated the data set myself, twice, so there's nothing wrong. My data set is 1024x768 in size, I used the size 1024x1024 for yolov5. Yes, I turned off HSV data enhancement.I use the Mosaic, mixup, scale, the blur and noise, brightness, contrast data enhancement method. Should I disable any data enhancements, or should I add any?  Look forward to your reply